# Magento 2: Can we show lifetime sales on the basis of processing order?

Tags: reports, magento2.3.0, dashboard, lifetime-sales

Currently, Lifetime sales on Magento admin dashboard are showing on the basis of complete orders. Can we show it on the basis of processing orders?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below step :

magento 2 admin panel ,

go to reports -> statistics -> click on refresh statistics -> on this page select all the values from the top and choose refresh lifetime statistics -> then click on submit !

Comment: already done this step.

Comment: Find any solution about this issue?